# Simplify PHP Validation of Multi-dimensional Array keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I simplify this code which validates multi-dimensional arrays before accessing one of its values?

```
<?php
function some_function($a) {
  if (isset($a) &&
    isset($a['container']) &&
    isset($a['container']['level1']) &&
    isset($a['container']['level1']['item1']) {
    print $a['container']['level1']['item1'];
  }
}
?>
```

Is there a simpler or better way to check that the keys exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do a single `isset($a['container']['level']['item1'])`. It'll check all of the keys in-order, and bail if any don't exist. There's  no need to test your way "down" the tree.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly without throwing any notice errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the innermost value:

```
<?php
function some_function($a) {
  if (isset($a) &&
    isset($a['container']['level1']['item1']) {
    print $a['container']['level1']['item1'];
  }
}
?>
```